# Confused: PostgreSQL 10 new kind of versioning?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 10 is the new main version after 9.6. But if you look at postgresql.org you will find 10.1?

https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1801/
Is 10.1 a new bugfix release for 10.0?

Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: I’m not sure, but probably they use 10 for version 10.1, just for some time because they don’t have 10.2 or another 10.x version. I haven’t seen version 10.0 for download only 10.1 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 10, the [versioning method](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning) was changed. From the linked page:

> Beginning with version 10, a major release is indicated by increasing
>   the first part of the version, e.g. 10 to 11. Before version 10, a
>   major release was indicated by increasing either the first or second
>   part of the version number, e.g. 9.5 to 9.6.

Thus 10 is the major version, 10.1 is the first point release of version 10. 10.2 is due out [Feb 8th, 2018](https://www.postgresql.org/developer/roadmap)